# PHP-CGI.EXE Creating Files as read only - WordPress 4.2.3 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: php

Whenever I attempt to update a plugin or change my configuration for W3 Total Cache, if wordpress creates a new file, it's created with the Read Only attribute. I can upload and delete content without issue. It's just updating a plugin or the w3total cache config. I removed the read only attribute from the w3 total cache config file and the changes are saved successfully, subsequent updates fail because the newly created config file is read only. I've confirmed it's PHP-CGI that's changing the attribute, because on the successful config update I see PHP-CGI changing the attribute. I've tried every combination of permissions / ownership I could think of. Including using AppPool identities and "Connect As", running as administrators and non-admins. I'm just not sure why the read only attribute is getting set.

If I create a text file via PHP myself, the read only attribute isn't applied. I'm on PHP 5.5.12, I even tried upgrading to the latest.

![Image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD2yw.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue, my site had the following in wp-config.php. Also WP-config.php had to be placed at the site root

```
 define('FS_CHMOD_DIR', true );
 define('FS_CHMOD_FILE', true );
 define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Removing the above resolved the issue.